# Problemwith VBA run time error 91 when webscraping

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I'm using VBA for some web scraping. The code works just fine on my computer with excel 2016 and IE10. However, when running on other machines (having IE11) I get run time error 91 (Object or variable not set). Here is part of my code:

```
Dim IE As Object
Dim oHTML_Element As IHTMLElement

Set w = New InternetExplorer
w.Navigate url
w.Visible = True

Do While (w.Busy Or w.READYSTATE <> READYSTATE.READYSTATE_COMPLETE)
DoEvents
Loop

Set HTMLDoc = w.Document

If Not HTMLDoc.all.Item("userName") Is Nothing Then

HTMLDoc.all.Item("userName").Value = zuser
HTMLDoc.all.Item("password").Value = zpass
HTMLDoc.all.Item("submit").Click

Do While (w.Busy Or w.READYSTATE <> READYSTATE.READYSTATE_COMPLETE)
DoEvents
Loop

For Each oHTML_Element In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("a")
If (InStr(oHTML_Element.href, "studentEnquiry.do?ex=preEx") > 0) Then
oHTML_Element.Click
Exit For
End If
Next

Do While (w.Busy Or w.READYSTATE <> READYSTATE.READYSTATE_COMPLETE)
DoEvents
Loop
'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:4"))
HTMLDoc.all.Item("StudentNumber").Value = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(row, "B").Value

End if
```

The code throws the error at this line:

```
HTMLDoc.all.Item("StudentNumber").Value = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(row, "B").Value
```

I tried delaying the execution and hoping the page is fully loaded but that did not solve the problem. I'd truly appreciate your help.

Comment: What is the value of `row` at that point? It is not `Dim`ed in your sample. It if it 0 that's your problem there.

Comment: Also, where is W Dim'd? Did you add a reference to `Microsoft Internet Controls`?

Comment: @Brad row is defined somewhere else in the code and its value is 7-did not include that part in my sample as not to add any distraction.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the line that blows up, inspect all the objects involved: one of them is `Nothing`.

Comment: @RyanWildry Yes I did add the reference. I just noted my w! Cannot think of it as a reason for the code not to run on some machines! As for now I do not have access to any machine where the code is throwing the error so cannot try to see if there is any difference. Will give it a try! Thank you.

Comment: @Mat'sMug It is the html element with the name "StudentNumber" which I'm trying to fill in. I just cannot figure out why this is happing on some machines and works absolutely fine on others.

Comment: Well then, you have your answer! Now handle runtime errors and figure out a work-around when the `StudentNumber` element doesn't exist.

Comment: you can try "downgrading" from `InternetExplorer` to a `WebBrowser` control

Comment: @Mat'sMug not really Mat, it is baffling me as it does not happen always. Not knowing the reason is making the whole thing difficult to address, especially that I cannot test and rely on the result on one machine. I suspect the IE as I said but cannot get around the problem.

Comment: @Slai does it have the same capabilities?

Comment: Yes. It is in the same SHDocVw Library as InternetExplorer, and for the most part I expect it to work with very minimal changes to the code. Another thing to try instead is if you can figure out how to run InternetExplorer in comparability mode.